# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with PHP no data imported

Tags: php, mysql

What I try to accomplish is to Export data from Excel 2013 and upload the data to a remote server. The data will be kept in Excel and refreshed weekly. I use MySQL 5.x and PHP 5.3.x and work on a Windows 7 system development environment using WAMP. I did a lot of research in the Internet but could not solve the problem.

This is my table:

```
$query = "CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t0` (  
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  
  `fromport` CHAR(10) NOT NULL ,  
  `kabatas` INT NULL ,  
  `eminonu` INT NULL ,  
  `bostanci` INT NULL ,  
  `maltepe` INT NULL ,  
  `kartal` INT NULL ,  
  `buyukada` INT NULL ,  
  `heybeliada` INT NULL ,  
  `burgazada` INT NULL ,  
  `kinaliada` INT NULL ,  
  `sedefadasi` INT NULL ,  
  `fromtime` CHAR(10) NULL ,  
  `fromtype` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,  
  `company` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,  
  `duration` CHAR(10) NULL ,  
  `price` FLOAT NULL ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )  
;";
```

This is the PHP part for LOAD DATA:

```
$query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "c:/transportation/' . $filename . '.txt" INTO TABLE ' . $filename . ' LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n" IGNORE 1 LINES;';  
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

The test data is:

> ```
> no    fromport    kabatas eminonu bostanci    maltepe kartal  buyukada    heybeliada  burgazada   kinaliada   sedefadasi  fromtime    fromtype    company duration
> ```
>
> price
>       KABATAŞ                       1                   08:30   Vapur   İDO 01:30    5.00 TL
>       KABATAŞ                       1                   09:30   Vapur   İDO 01:30    5.00 TL
>       KABATAŞ                       1                   13:00   Vapur   İDO 01:30    5.00 TL
>       KABATAŞ                       1                   15:00   Vapur   İDO 01:30    5.00 TL
>       KABATAŞ                       1                   19:00   Vapur   İDO 01:30    5.00 TL

Now:

There are no errors
There is no data in the table as a result (checking with MySQL Workbench)
The lines and with CR+LF, data delimited by TAB (checked with Notepad++)

Any thoughts?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the test data incorrectly pasted, or does data actually start at line three? Because then you need to specify IGNORE 3 LINES instead. Also, you are not specifying which fields of the table to put the data into, an the number of fields and number of input columns aren't the same, so it should fail.